# Using chartjs to limit data?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, heatmap

I have a react chartjs project that uses `chartjs-chart-matrix` to render a heatmap.  My code config looks like so:

```
const getHeatmapConfig = ({
  heatmapData,
  getBackgroundColor,
  xAxisLabels,
  tissues: items,
  openMenu,
  title
}) => ({
  type: 'matrix',
  data: {
    datasets: [
      {
        data: heatmapData,
        backgroundColor: function (ctx) {
          const value = ctx.dataset.data[ctx.dataIndex].v;
          return getBackgroundColor(colors, value);
        },
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'category',
        labels: xAxisLabels,
        offset: true,
        position: 'bottom',
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          autoSkip: true,
          maxRotation: 90,
          minRotation: 90
        },
        grid: {
          display: false,
          drawBorder: false
        }
      },
      y: {
        type: 'category',
        labels: items,
        reverse: false,
        offset: true,
        grid: {
          display: false,
          drawBorder: false
        },
        ticks: {
          autoSkip: true
        }
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: false,
      title: {
        align: 'center',
        font: { size: 15 },
        display: true,
        text: title
      },
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          title() {
            return '';
          },
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

My question is - I want to ensure that their are never more than 50 values and labels on the x axis but there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way of limiting the data like this.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should limit the array of labels that you pass into your component.
For example: `xAxisLabels.slice(0, 50)`